# Ubuntu 13.10 showing BUSYBOX?

Tags: busybox

can any one plzzz tell me how to get rid of this BUSYBOX in Ubuntu 13.10 ?? :/

linux was working fine, but 2 days ago my laptop was out of battery and it shutdown. When I restart it, Ubuntu was showing this busybox

[image]

Need help PLZZZ !!!

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054098/ubuntu-showing-busybox-in-13-10

Comment: If answer solved your problem you should close question

Answer (score 1):

Probably your system is broken, easiest way of restore is to reinstall it.

Otherwise you can boot from live CD and post content of your system log from `/var/log/boot.log` but not this on live CD, this on computer drive.

To recover your files you have to boot from live CD/USB (like when you install Ubuntu), select try Ubuntu and you can access your files via Files (nautilus) standard app.

It's not possible to diagnose why this problem occured without your system log.

Comment: how can I retrieve my data ??

Comment: Isn't there any other option ??

Is this problem related or pointing towards any hard-disk issues ??

why this issue occurred ?

As @Adrian said that my LVM volume group is busted, how ?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: can I use BootRepair app ?

Comment: BootRepair would help if there were something broken in booting. You have problem with your OS, so it wol't help You. However you can copy your files this way.

Comment: I have reinstalled the Ubuntu.

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved (click on the "tick" mark on the left of answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your LVM volume group is busted, and your /root partition can't mount.

You'll need to fix that. Or possible reinstall things.

Comment: how can I fix it ?

Comment: Isn't there any other option ??

Is this problem related or pointing towards any hard-disk issues ??

why this issue occurred ?

As @Adrian said that my LVM volume group is busted, how ?